# Speech Recognition of Emergency Radio Recordings

Tags: speech-recognition

New to speech recognition, so please pardon my ignorance. I'm trying to get a transcript of emergency radio announcements [example1](https://storage.googleapis.com/yafp/ttstest.flac) [example2](https://storage.googleapis.com/yafp/ttsvoiceonly.wav). Obviously, I'm doing something wrong because none of the advanced ASR (automatic speech recognition) tools can make any sense out of it.

I've tried [IBM Watson](https://www.ibm.com/watson/services/speech-to-text/), [Google Speech](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/?hl=en_US#p/speech/v1/speech.speech.recognize) and even [Cobalt](https://demo.cobaltspeech.com/). None of them can even glean the most basic information from the audio.

So here's the two-part question. Is audio like the examples above even usable through ASR tools? Is there some transformations I should be doing before sending through the APIs?

Comment: Do you understand how speech recognition works?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is audio like the examples above even usable through ASR tools?

Yes, you can recognize such things pretty reliably but you have to build a custom ASR system since conventional ones will not work with such audio quality.

> Is there some transformations I should be doing before sending through the APIs?

No, it is much more productive to use specialized models trained on your very specific kind of data.

Cobalt could build you a custom solution for this. You can use open source toolkits like Kaldi to build the models yourself. Another company to check for specialized solution for this kind of audio is [Adacel](http://www.adacel.com), they work on airport towers, so have similar type of audio.

For research on the subject you can check the project about custom [Apollo mission transcription system](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/55eb/9d066893706a48e02e09e2c32306d821636b.pdf).

You also need to put more effort on getting better quality audio.

Comment: excellent! although it appears I've got my work cut out for me, this is exactly what I needed to know.